# Consequences of early-exiting BFS after reaching the target node in Dinic's algorithm

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, max-flow

In a typical exposition (or implementation), Dinic's algorithm executes a full BFS traversal of the residual graph starting from the source node in each phase. If the target node is unreachable, the algorithm terminates. Note that the target node is not necessarily the last node BFS will visit. If the target node is reachable, it will execute a DFS to compute a blocking flow and augment appropriately.

What happens if we modify the algorithm to run a "partial" BFS in the sense that it stops the BFS once it reaches the target node? Specifically:

1. Does this break the algorithm (i.e. causes incorrect results)?
2. If not, does it change (help or hurt) the time complexity?
3. Assuming that this change is not allowable (or have negative consequences) in the general case, does this conclusion change if we assume the graph in question is bipartite?

NOTE: With the early-exit change, the first step of the algorithm becomes identical to the Edmonds-Karp algorithm, but the way it subsequently handles blocking/augmenting flows remains different (at least on the surface).

Some relevant findings discussing what seems to be the same idea:

- [These lecture notes](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-f14/www/lectures/lec11/dinic.pdf) seem to suggest such early-exiting ("*Once t is reached, no more levels are generated.*"), but the implementation code thereafter doesn't seem to do this.
- [These notes](https://hochbaum.ieor.berkeley.edu/files/IEOR266-lecture-notes-F2017.pdf) also seem to suggest the same approach.

Thanks!